# Google web font loader not working on default android browser

Tags: android, css, google-webfonts

I am creating a [basic site for a client](http://balmainplumber.net.au/). I am using the nifty [Slabtext](http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/slabText/) to have responsive headlines.

I am loading the League Gothic font (which is used by the creator of Slabtext) using Google's [web font loader](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader). All is well, and I am able to trigger the slabtext to start *after* the fonts are loaded using the `.active()` callback.

```
$(function() {
    WebFont.load({
     custom: {
                families: ['League Gothic'], // font-family name
                urls : ['/templates/joomstrap/css/webfonts/stylesheet.css'] 
      },
      active: function() {
                jQuery('.do-slab-text').slabText();
            }
        });
    });
```

Unfortunately, this doesnt seem to work on Android's default browser.  It works on Chrome on Android. Its also working perfectly on iOS. And all the desktop browsers.

Comment: i am also experiencing problems with the default android browser + dolphin and google web fonts